# $B = \{\{x\}: x \in X -\{x_0\}\} \cup \{X\}$ is a base for a topology over $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty, fixed set $x_{0} \in X$ arbitrary. Show that $B = \{\{x\}: x \in X -\{x_0\}\} \cup \{X\}$ is a base for a topology over $X$.

Definition. We say that a collection $B$ of openings of $X$ is a base of openings for the topological space $X$ if all openings can be written as union and a subcollection of $B$.

Does anyone know how to prove this fact? doesn't make sense to me, because this base will have only the set $X$. Can someone help me? appreciate.

Comment: If $X$ has more than one point, $B$ contains sets other than $X$. For instance, let $X=\Bbb N$ and $x_0=0$. Then $$B=\big\{\{n\}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\big\}\cup\{\Bbb N\}\,:$$ it contains the sets $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, and so on as well as the set $\Bbb N$.

Comment: What does it mean $X\{x_0\}$?

Comment: "offer"?? You must mean "open". "openings"??? You must mean "open sets". It's easier to think about these things clearly when you don't have a private, misleading language for them.

Comment: It's actually open base

Comment: @Ero, It's actually $X-\{x_0\}$.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: @milou: Show that the family of unions of members of $B$ is $\{X\}\cup\wp\big(X\setminus\{x_0\}\big)$, and verify that this is a topology on $X$.

Comment: How can I show that family of unions of members of $B$ is $\{X\}\cup p(X-\{x_0\})$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you help me with this? I didn't understand what you told me to do, why prove it $\{X\}\cup℘(X∖{x_0})$ is a topology? Is every base a topology?

Comment: @milou: No, not every base is a topology. In particular, $B$ is not a base for the topology that it generates, which is $$\tau=\{X\}\cup\wp\big(X\setminus\{x_0\}\big)\,.$$ To show that $\tau$ is a topology, verify that it satisfies the definition: show that it contains $\varnothing$ and $X$, that $U\cap V\in\tau$ whenever $U,V\in\tau$, and that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$ whenever $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$. To show that $\tau$ is the family of unions of members of $B$, do the obvious thing: show that if $\mathscr{B}\subseteq B$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{B}\in\tau$, and that if $U\in\tau$, ...

Comment: ... then there is a $\mathscr{B}\subseteq B$ such that $U=\bigcup\mathscr{B}$. All of these steps are very straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this elementary lemma:

A collection $B$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base for a topology on $X$ iff

(i). $\;\cup B=X\;$ (i.e. each $x\in X$ belongs to at least one $b\in B$ ), and

(ii). If $b,b'\in B$ and $x\in b\cap b'$ then there exists $b''\in B$ with $x\in b''\subseteq b\cap b'.$